# User friendly Order Form

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am attempting to create a user friendly application that allows the user to buy pencils, pens, and erasers. A total cost should be displayed.
My code mostly works except for one problem. the numbers that the user inputs in the boxes (how many pens/pencils/erasers they would like to buy) are not being used by the code. if I add a value manually to the code it performs the calculation (<input type="number" **value="3"** placeholder="# of erasers" min="0" id="numOfErasers">) could somebody please help me with getting the calculation to use user inputted numbers?
here's my code (JavaScript/HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    
     <title> Pencils Pens Erasers </title>
    
    <script>

        //this is the function that calcultes the cost
        
        function costCalculator () {
            var total = penCost + pencilCost + eraserCost;
            return total;
            }
        
    </script>
    
</head>
    
    
    
    
<body>
    
<form>
    
    <!--this is the order form-->
    
    <br>
    <u><b>please indicate how many of each you wish to order:</b></u> 
    <br><br>
    
    Pens:<input type="number" placeholder="# of pens" min="0" id="numOfPens"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    Pencils:<input type="number" placeholder="# of pencils" min="0" id="numOfPencils"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    Erasers:<input type="number" placeholder="# of erasers" min="0" id="numOfErasers">
    <br><br>
    
    please select which province you are ordering from:<select name="Province" id="whichProvince"> 
    <option value="1" id="SK"> Saskatchewan  </option>
    <option value="2" id="AB"> Alberta  </option>
    <option value="3" id="MB"> Manitoba  </option>
    
    </select>
    
    </form>    
    
    
     <script>
         
//these are all my variables
         
        var pens = document.getElementById("numOfPens").value
        var pencils = document.getElementById("numOfPencils").value
        var erasers = document.getElementById("numOfErasers").value
        
        var penCost = 0.50 * pens
        var pencilCost = 0.30 * pencils 
        var eraserCost = 1.00 * erasers
        var province = document.getElementById("whichProvince").value
        var totalCost = costCalculator()     
        
//this code adds taxes and discount to the total price based on province
            
    if (province == 1) {
            totalCost = (5 / 100) * totalCost + totalCost;
        } else if (province == 1 && totalCost>30) {
            totalCost = totalCost-5       
        } else if (province == 2) {
            totalCost = (5 / 100) * totalCost + totalCost;
            totalCost = totalCost + 2;
        } else if (province == 3) {
            totalCost = (6 / 100) * totalCost + totalCost;
            totalCost = totalCost + 2;
        }
        
         
         
        
    /*     function test () {
            window.alert(total)
        }
    */   
        function test2 () {
            window.alert(totalCost)
        }
         
         
         
            
    
  document.write ("<br>" + " The total cost of your purchase will be: " + "<b>" + totalCost + "</b>" + "<br>")    
        
    </script> 
    
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    
    <p><p align=center>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onclick="costCalculator(); test2();" >
    </p> 
    
    
    
    
</body>
    


</html>
```

Comment: Sorry this is my first ever question on this site and I just realized how messy my question looks...I would recommend copy/ paste it so that you can see it the same way as me.

Comment: You've to get familiar with the concept of [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Comment: @BennetSchmidt no worries, you'll learn. SO has a snippet editor (`<>` symbol in the question editor). Paste your code into there and click the `tidy` button which fixes the indentation and nesting. Then manually remove redundant line breaks and click `save & insert into post`.

Comment: I really need this answered as soon as possible. Can somebody *please* help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get familiar with [events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp). Below is a minimal working example, the main difference is that it uses a button at the end with `onclick` attribute calling the `costCalculator` function.

```js
function costCalculator() {
  var pensTotal = document.getElementById("numOfPens").value * 0.5;
  var pencilsTotal = document.getElementById("numOfPencils").value * 0.3;
  var erasersTotal = document.getElementById("numOfErasers").value;
  var total = parseFloat(pensTotal + pencilsTotal + erasersTotal);
  var province = document.getElementById("whichProvince").value;
  if (province == 1) {
    total = (5 / 100) * total + total;
    if (total > 30) {
      total -= 5;
    }
  } else if (province == 2) {
    total = (5 / 100) * total + total;
    total += 2;
  } else if (province == 3) {
    total = (6 / 100) * total + total;
    total += 2;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<label for="numOfPens">Pens:</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="# of pens" min="0" id="numOfPens"><br/>

<label for="numOfPencils">Pencils:</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="# of pencils" min="0" id="numOfPencils"><br/>

<label for="numOfErasers">Erasers:</label>
<input type="number" placeholder="# of erasers" min="0" id="numOfErasers"><br/>

<label for="whichProvince">please select which province you are ordering from:</label>
<select name="Province" id="whichProvince">
  <option value="1" id="SK"> Saskatchewan</option>
  <option value="2" id="AB"> Alberta </option>
  <option value="3" id="MB"> Manitoba </option>
</select><br/>

<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onclick="costCalculator()">
<p id="output"></p>
```

I've done a few other irrelevant changes to your code, I'll answer anything you need in the comments.

Comment: thank you so much for the help this was very useful! I will let you know if I need anything else.